# Sigmoidal neuron - linear separability

Tags: classification, neural-networks

I am struggling to write a simple proof for the following statement:

> The neuron's inputs are proportional to the probability of the respective feature in the input layer

In particular, I am not sure what $y'$ means here and how we get to an expression of $p(\mathbb{y}|x)$ that depends on $p(\mathbb{x}|y)/p(\mathbb{x}|y')$. Also not 100% sure what $n$ means.

source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02406.pdf

**EDIT 1**
I found this question to be a duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317615/hyperplanes-optimally-classify-data-when-inputs-are-conditionally-independent) older question. There, the author of the referenced paper points the reader in the right direction.

**EDIT 2**
In light of the answer provided, I feel that the only missing piece of the puzzle is equation (2) - below.

[image]

Comment: I assume you mean p(y|x) in terms of ...

Comment: I agree, it's a bit awkward to use n as proportionality constant.

Comment: In another thread (added link to Q, see Edit 1), the author of the referred paper says that $n$ is the sample size and points to some sort of Signal to Noise ratio and the assumption that the SNR grows like $\sqrt{n}$. I still don't get where eq (2) comes from: although I get the conditional independence part, I don't understand the $n p(x_j)$ exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y'$ is the other class, i.e. `y-not`. If you get rid of the log and exp in the denominator of Eq. (1), you'll have:
$$p(y|x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\log\left(\frac{p(x,y')}{p(x,y)}\right)\right)}=\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x,y)+p(x,y')}$$
The denominator needs to be $p(x)$ due to Bayes Rule, so $y'$ is really the negative class. 
$n$ is just a proportionality constant, which is also related to your yellow-quoted line. i.e. they actually mean something like $h_j\propto p(x_j)$.